# Trying to use a non-static object in a List of objects

Tags: c#, razor

I am working with Razor Components and have a question about using `non-static values` in a `list of objects`.

I have the following code:

```
     @page "/CircularGauge/DefaultFunctionalities"

@using Syncfusion.EJ2.RazorComponents.CircularGauge



   <div class="control-section">
      <EjsCircularGauge ID="gauge" Axes="axes"></EjsCircularGauge>
   </div>

   @functions {
   int myInteger = 21;
   public List<Object> axes { get; set; } = new List<Object>
   {
   new
   {
      radius = "80%",
      startAngle = 230,
      endAngle = 130,
      majorTicks = new { width = "0px" },
      minorTicks = new { width = "0px" },
      lineStyle = new { width = 8, color = "#E0E0E0" },
      labelStyle = new { font = new { fontFamily = "Roboto", size =      "12px", fontWeight = "Regular" }, offset = -5 },
      pointers  = new List<Object>
      {
      new
      {
        value = 60,
        radius = "60%",
        color = "#757575",
        pointerWidth = 7,
        cap = new { radius = 8, color = "#757575", border = new { width = 0 } },
        needleTail = new { color = "#757575", length = "25%" }
    }
}
 }
  };
  }
```

Source: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core-blazor/CircularGauge/DefaultFunctionalities

I have a integer I am using in my code like:

```
     int myInteger = 21;
```

what I wanted to do is at the code above, at:

```
      pointers  = new List<Object>
      {
      new
      {
        ****value = 60,****
        radius = "60%",
        color = "#757575",
        pointerWidth = 7,
        cap = new { radius = 8, color = "#757575", border = new { width = 0 } }
     }
```

Was changing the value of `value` to my local integer, but that is not possible.

[image: This is why]

I'm stuck in finding a solution around this. is there anyone with some knowledge about this?

Comment: In the code that you've presented, I can't see where the `int myInteger` is.

Comment: my bad, I edited it for you.

Comment: if you make it public, can you use it then?

Comment: Or `public static int myInteger`

Comment: unfortunately I can't reach any code outside this newly created object (public or not) because it only expects static values.

Comment: so you cannot make myInteger static?

Comment: yes making it static does work, but it does not seem a very `clean` solution to me, still thanks for the suggestion @Jabberwocky

Comment: Why do you say it's not clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing a property, using an inline constructor. You can't access an instance field in an inline constructor because the compiler cannot ensure which one is going to be done first.

You should define the `myInteger` as static `private static int myInteger`. Or you can establish the value of the property in the constructor, and there you can use a local variable on the constructor.

But, if you want to define a constant variable like that one, I'd rather recommend you more to do it like this:

```
private const int MY_INTEGER = 21;
```

Comment: nice one, although I should have mentioned my `real` integer is not constant. the reason I'm trying to avoid `static` is because you should not use static variables to keep track of something that you might have more than one of. because it can be a problem in the future.

Comment: So the purpose of that variable is to create some kind of index? Because maybe you need to use Guid.NewID() to create unique values and ensure that you can distinguish one object to another.